# Каким образом я могу присвоить значение переменным, которые рассчитываются внутри конструкции switch?

Tags: c#, winforms, switch

Только начал изучать C#. Внутри конструкции `switch` рассчитываю значение переменной `R`. После закрытия конструкции switch пытаюсь совершить действия с рассчитанными `R` (их семь, как и семь конструкций `switch`).

Выдает ошибку: `Использование локальной переменной R7, которой не присвоено значение`

Ниже код. Таких конструкции `switch` у меня 7, соответственно выдает 7 ошибок.

```cs
switch (comboBox7.Text)
{
    case "1":
        R7 = metric7 * 1;
        break;
    case "2":
        R7 = metric7 * 2;
        break;
    case "3":
        R7 = metric7 * 3;
        break;
    case "4":
        R7 = metric7 * 4;
        break;
    case "5":
        R7 = metric7 * 5;
        break;
}
Rsum = R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6 + R7;
textBox18.Text = Convert.ToString(Rsum / 5);
```

Comment: а если `comboBox7.Text` будет равно "чебурек"? чему тогда будет равно `R7`?

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что у вас где-то задается переменная без значения по умолчанию. Сделайте там `int R7 = -1;` например, где `int` - тип, а `-1` - то, чему эта переменная будет равна по умолчанию. Также, ваш `switch` можно вовсе убрать простым `R7 = metric7 * int.Parse(comboBox7.Text);` (а лучше использовать `int.TryParser()`). Также я прям уверен, что можно эти `R1-7` тоже как-то упростить. В программирование есть правило, DRY - не повторяй себя, следуйте ему, не пишите повторяющийся код, если он у вас есть, то значит его можно упростить или объединить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для преобразования строки в число вам не нужен `switch`. Вместо этого можно использовать `int.Parse` или `int.TryParse`.

```cs
if (int.TryParse(comboBox7.Text, out int number))
{
    R7 = metric7 * number;
    int sum = (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4 + R5 + R6 + R7) / 5;
    textBox18.Text = sum.ToString();
}
else
{
    textBox18.Text = "Выберите значение";
}
```

Если же вам нужно объявить и использовать переменную вне блока кода, в котором она присваивается, можете ей присвоить значение по умолчанию, например `int R7 = 0` вместо просто `int R7`.